# Does PowerShell produce a side effect that creates a file named with a number?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, filenames, user-accounts, side-effects

My notebook came back from a repair yesterday. Its HDD was replaced with an SSD, with a fresh installation of *Windows 10 Home Single Language (Update 1903)*, no backup. It also came with an administrator account called something like 'user'. This detail was bothering.

I should have made a better research fist, but I was too impatient. So, my first try was changing user name on Control Panel. But the user folder name remained the same. Then, I executed `Control UserPasswords2` and changed the username there. Running it second time, I couldn't see any user listed, but I just had to reboot. I don't remember what user name was there before, but by then the new one was displayed. But, again, the folder name didn't change.

I noticed another strange thing: my Wi-Fi was duplicated. I could use, let's say, 'NET' and 'NET 2'. This was solved by removing both networks. Just in case, I checked whether the Temp folder was duplicated, and it wasn't.

Then, I made a longer research and many places were indicating a solution which required changing all matching user path values in registry, about 100 entries. Using a PowerShell script looked a good idea. I didn't found any code for that, but I was already playing with PowerShell. Trying some simple things.

I thought that sticking to `Get-` commands and avoiding `Set-` would be safe. But when I executed the following:

`PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Get-ItemProperty`

The output was:

```
    Diretório: C:\Windows\system32


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       14/07/2019     11:21              8 1
-a----       14/07/2019     11:10              2 2
Get-ItemProperty : Não é possível localizar o caminho 'C:\Windows\system32\3' porque ele não existe.
No linha:1 caractere:11
+ 1, 2, 3 | Get-ItemProperty
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\system32\3:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

I found it strange, because there was a table with information mixed with an error message, like it did altered something.

I looked at System32 folder and there were two files, without extension, named as `1` and `2`. Those are the only files created and modified today in that folder. And `1` is older than `2`.

Here is what is inside `1`:

`3`

The file `2` is empty.

The files stay there even closing the PowerShell.

Here is the history of commands I executed at the last (and only, I think) session:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> help GetItemProperty 

PS C:\Windows\system32> GetChildItem -path HKCU:\ | GetItemProperty

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\ | Get-ItemProperty

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\ | Get-ItemProperty Name

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\ | Get-ItemProperty -Name

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\ | Get-ItemProperty -Property "Name"

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\ | Get-ItemProperty

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -path HKCU:\

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1,2,3 | Get-ItemProperty

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where $_ > 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where ($_ > 2)

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where $PSItem > 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where $_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -($_ > 2)

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where-Object $_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where-Object -$_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ = 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ == 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where - $_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ -eq 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ -greater 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ -gt 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -$_ -gt 0

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -gt 0

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where-Object -$ -gt 1

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where-Object -$_ -gt 1

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where-Object -gt 1

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where -Property $_ Value 2

PS C:\Windows\system32> help Where

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where { $_ > 1 }

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | % { $_ > 1 }

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | % { $_ > 1 } | Write

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | % { $_ > 1 } | Write-Verbose

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where { $_ -eq 1 }

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Where { $_ -gt 1 }

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | % { $_ -gt 1 }

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | % { if ($_ -gt 1) { Write $_ } }

PS C:\Windows\system32> help Write

PS C:\Windows\system32> 1, 2, 3 | Get-ItemProperty
```

I'm not planning changing registry, I think just putting back the old name and creating a separate account is fine. But should I be worry with that two files?

Sorry for the long post. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you're doing "> 1" you're creating a file called "1".  Or "> 2" for "2".  It's (almost) the same as `| out-file 1`.  Greater than in powershell is "-gt".  You seemed to catch on to that later.

```
echo hi > 1  # makes a file, encoded in unicode
echo hi > 2  # can also overwrite a file
echo hi >> 1  # append a file, but can mix encodings
echo hi >> 2
```

Yes, these make a file called "1", even with a terminating error.

```
1 | where $_ > 1
1 | where ($_ > 1) 
1 | where -($_ > 1)
1 | where $psitem > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why was I obligated to use "-eq" instead of the usual operator. I saw a similar problem in Linux forum, my error was right on the wrong syntax. But, why is "2" created first? I can't find a valid command with "> 2", this is why it's empty? The first valid command with " >" uses 1, and I think "1" contains 3 because the file is written from scratch every iteration.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I can't find one that doesn't have an error as output. Does it write in a file regardless of that?

Comment: I didn't show the outputs because the question was already long.

Comment: It's not an error.  You're just doing something else.

Comment: Powershell is sort of like C.  Very expressive, but you can shoot yourself in the foot.  You can do a similar if mistake.  `if ($i = 1) { 'yes' } `

Comment: I tried this `1, 2, 3 | Where $_ > 10` on another location and it outputs an error, but still it creates a file named '10'. I guess the error message doesn't mean there was no action.

Comment: It's just one backquote for code.  The error is no scriptblock with $_.  `1 | where { $_ > 1 } `

Comment: I could do this with no error.  `get-process | where handles > 1`.  It looks for handles that are nonzero then saving to a file called 1.

Comment: Sorry for extending the scope of the question a little bit. What I'm trying to say is that even when there's no scriptblock, PowerShell creates the file, but empty, since it can't do anything with an error. But I think it should emit a warning about that.

Comment: Oh yeah the warnings could be better in many things.  Be careful not to overwrite a file too with > or copy-item.

Comment: You're right.  Even with a terminating error, it makes the file.

Comment: I already don't like > anyway, because the file ends up in unicode. This just makes me dislike it more.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Just because there's a `<` it doesn't mean it will generate an error. But I meant the case when it is an error, but still achieve an action. I'm not sure how to explain it, but it seams like it's parsing and executing at the 'same' time, instead of first decide whether the whole thing is valid.

Comment: I think you're explaining it right.  At least you get no file this way.  `1, 2, 3 | Where $_  | out-file 10`  > is a strange case.

Comment: I'll be careful with PowerShell more than in general now :)

Comment: A blog about the "powershell gotchas" would be good to check out.

Comment: Yes, it's good to discover this kind of thing at the beginning.